# How to restore RAID5 Array

Tags: linux, grub2, data-recovery, mdadm, raid5

I have a RAID5 array consisting of 3 identical 2TB drives. Suddenly GRUB wouldn't boot anymore and gave the error out of disk.

Eventually booted a livecd and ran some mdadm commands:

`mdadm --examine /dev/sda1` gives no md superblock detected on /dev/sda1.
But when examining `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdc1/` gives the output in the attached photo's.

[image: <code>mdadm --examine sdb1</code>]
[image: <code>mdadm --examine sdc1</code>]

Any help in solving or diagnosing this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Screenshots, seriously? You have two disks there, can't you just assemble it? Error messages?

Comment: Instead of screenshots you can always start a sshd from your live-system, remote-login and then copy'n'paste the terminal contents as text. Also, don't forget to look at `/proc/mdstat`.

Comment: Show the output of `cat /proc/partitions`

Comment: `cat /proc/partitions` gives the following output:
`Major minor #blocks Name
8             32 1953514584 sdc
8             33 1953513472 sdc1
8             16 1953524584 sdb
8             17 1953523472 sdb1
8               0 1953514584 sda
8               1 1953513472 sda1
8             48       7574304 sdd
8             49       7573280 sdd1`

I am sorry for the mess, I can not get the right lay out of the table in this comment box...

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd do `mdadm --assemble --scan /dev/md0 --name server:0` and that would assemble the array, or maybe tell you to `mdadm --run /dev/md0` to assemble it degraded. You can also explicitly give the devices instead of using `--scan`.

Then you can get your data off (or add a drive to rebuild).

That should work. Of course, something happened to erase the superblock off of one of your drives; you should find out what it was. It may have caused other damage.